# Como evitar que se desaparezca el menu?

Tags: html, css

Cordial saludo a tod@s, tengo un problema en HTML y CSS, la pagina en mas de 815px se muestra en forma de filas, y al presionar el menu esta funciona de forma correcta, pero al bajar de 815px esta se coloca en column y al dar clik en el menu este desaparece, no logro dar con el chiste.
Ahora no se como compartir el código, ya que no se si me acepte pegar todo el css y el html.

Este seria la parte del nav, donde al dar click te lleva a la parte de la pagina. Solo agrego la parte del nav, pero esta se entiende que al dar click te envía hacia una section la cual contiene un id correspondiente al de la etiqueta a

```
 <nav id="navbar" class="navbar">
            <header>JS Documentation</header>
         
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#introductioin" class="nav- 
  link">Introduction</a> </li>
                <li><a href="#what_you_should_already_know" 
  class="nav-link">What you should already know</a> </li>
                <li><a href="#constants" class="nav- 
  link">Constants</a> </li>
                <li><a href="#data_types" class="nav-link">Data 
  Types</a> </li>
                <li><a href="#if_else_statement" class="nav- 
  link">if...else statement</a> </li>
                <li><a href="#while_statement" class="nav-link">While 
  Statement</a> </li>
                <li><a href="#function_declarations" class="nav- 
  link">Function Declarations</a> </li>
                <li><a href="#reference" class="nav- 
  link">Reference</a> </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
```

y esta seria la parte del css

```
    html{
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
    }

    body{
    background-color: rgb(233, 233, 206);
    color: rgb(63, 61, 61);
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    overflow-y: hidden;    
    }
    header{
    font-size: 1.7em;
    padding: 1em .4em;
    color: black;
    
    }

    article{
    margin-left: 1.5em;
    }

    p{
    margin-bottom: 1em;
    }



    a{
    
    text-decoration: none;
    color: rgb(63, 61, 61);
    }

    code{
    display: block;
    padding: 1em 1em;
    margin: 0 0 1em 2em;
    background-color: rgb(219, 210, 210);
    white-space: pre-line;
    line-height: 2;
    color: rgb(59, 58, 58);
    border-radius: 5px;
    }

    .contenedor{
    display: flex;
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    }

   .navbar{
    width: 400PX;
    border-right: 4px solid rgb(143, 140, 140);
    }
    .navbar ul{
    height: 85vh;
    overflow-y: auto;
    
    }

    .navbar header{
    text-align: center;
    
    }

    .navbar ul li{
    border-top: 1px solid black;
    padding: 1em 1em 1em 1.5em;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    }

    .main-doc{
    width: 80%;
    height: 100vh;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    padding: 2em;
    flex-shrink: 2;

    }

    .main-doc li{
    margin: 0 0 1em 4em;
    }

    .main-doc ul ul{
    margin: 1em 0em;
    }

    #reference a{
    text-decoration: underline;
    color: blueviolet;
    }
    @media (max-width:815px){
    .contenedor{
        flex-direction: column;
    }
    .navbar{
        position: relative;
        top: 0;
        width: 100%;
    }
    .navbar ul{
       
        height: 250px;
        border: 2px solid rgb(143, 140, 140);
        
        
    }
    .main-doc{
        /* width: 100%;
        height: 100%;  */
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
        padding: 4em;
        /* margin-top: 50px; */
        
    
      }
    }
```

Comment: Y el codigo? Sin el como podriamos ayudarte?

Comment: Agrega el código como un *Fragmento de código*; en el editor es el botón con "<>", ahí puedes colocar tu html/css/js.